# From OBJ to WebGL - Python GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webgl

I have to write an application which takes an OBJ file (+MTL, +textures) and shows a 3D WebGL object in web browser. I use Google App Engine (Python).

I tried to use PyGame library to do it, but PyGame uses C code for performance, and only Pure Python libraries can be used with Google App Engine.

Are there any others libraries, which help me to do it? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Google app engine is irrelevant here, it's just where the files are coming from.

PyGame only runs on your PC, it's not suitable for this even if it was written in pure python.

The only library you need is the WebGL library itself and a place to host the files (GAE or 1000 other places will do) so they can be transferred to the target browser.

For example: http://www.chromeexperiments.com/webgl/

None of those are hosted on GAE (probably) yet they all display 3D WebGL objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are several free services that will do this for you - without the need to write any code. I'll mention ours, [Verold Studio](http://studio.verold.com), but there are others. If all you want is to spin a model on your page, definitely don't waste your time building this - there are lots of services that will do this for you.

If you need to write a custom application using your 3D data, you can build this using WebGL directly, or one of the rendering libraries like Three.js. We use Three.js internally, and if this is the way you choose to go I would recommend you check out our tools and the [Verold Engine](http://verold.com/verold-engine). The engine is our latest product, it's an extremely powerful way to easily build 3D applications. Our first reference app is [Falling in Circles](http://labs.verold.com/falling-in-circles), check it out.